Given a compact submanifold $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $x \in M$, is the intersection $N = M \cap B_\epsilon(x)$ a topological ball?
Suppose that $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a compact topological submanifold (without boundary) of Euclidean space.
We know that the intersections of the open balls with the centers in $M$, that is,
$$
\left\{ M \cap B_\epsilon(x) : x \in M, \epsilon > 0 \right\}
$$
form a basis for the topology of $M$.
Given $N(x,\epsilon) = M \cap B_\epsilon(x)$ where $x \in M$ and $\epsilon > 0$, under what conditions is $N(x,\epsilon)$ a topological ball?
I am particularly interested in the case where $m := \dim M$ equals $m = n-1$.
The result is already true when submanifold is smooth, as discussed here.
I assume compactness for simplicity but that assumption is not essential.

The intersections need not be topological balls.
Let $P_n \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the path that goes through the following points, connecting each to the next with a horizontal or vertical line segment:
$\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}, 0 \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \right)$, $\left(0, \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \right)$, $\left(0, \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n}, 0 \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}, 0 \right)$
Intuitively, $P_n$ is a path that goes straight up from a point near $\left(\frac{1}{2n},0\right)$, to a height of about $\frac{1}{2^n}$, travels over to the y-axis, then back following the same path very closely (and yes, that's a multiplication in the first coordinate and exponentiation in the second - the idea is the $y$-coordinates shrink faster than the $x$-coordinates as $n$ grows).
Let $A$ be a path connecting the origin to the point $(1, 0)$ through the half-plane $y < 0$. Let $M = A \cup \bigcup_{i\geq 1}P_i$. I'll leave it as an exercise to show that $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.
Choose $\epsilon$ sufficiently small that we can pick an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon < \frac{1}{2n+1}$. Then $B_\epsilon(0,0)$ will intersect the $\left(0, \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \right)$, $\left(0, \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \right)$ segment of $P_n$, but not the $\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}, 0 \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \right)$ or $\left(\frac{1}{2n}, 0 \right)$, $\left(\frac{1}{2n - 1}, 0 \right)$ segments. But $B_\epsilon(0,0)$ intersects $P_m$ for each $m > n$, meaning that $B_\epsilon(0,0) \cap M$ is disconnected, and thus clearly not a ball.
Note that this construction will not work for smooth manifolds. Even if you smooth out the corners in the $P_n$, the map you get from $S^1$ to $M$ will not be smooth at the origin.
